# How to set up virtualhosts on Ubuntu dev machine in arbitrary directories, with write permissions for Apache and me?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lamp, file-permissions

I am on my XUbuntu 12.04 development machine, and I have installed the LAMP stack using `tasksel install lamp-server`. I've been trying to set up virtualhosts in my personal projects directories, without success. I've looked at the example vhost config in the apache docs ([Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#purename)). I've tried suggestions from a variety of tutorials and blog posts, and had a variety or problems (Timeout, "It works" page instead of index.php, 403 Forbidden).

I have enabled the userdir module and added myself to the www-data group. Permissions and owners for the relevant files:

- `/home/dan/Projects/phpinfo/www`: 775, owned by dan:www-data
- `/home/dan/Projects/phpinfo/www/index.php`: 664, owned by dan:www-data

Despite the fact that the site's web root an everything below it is readable by anyone, I cant't cd into it as the www-data user (using `sudo -s www-data`).

This is what my configuration looks like right now. I get a 403 Forbidden when I curl `http://phpinfo.local`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName phpinfo.local

    DocumentRoot /home/dan/Projects/phpinfo/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/dan/Projects/phpinfo/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted /home/dan/Projects/phpinfo/www
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/dan/Projects/phpinfo/logs/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /home/dan/Projects/phpinfo/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The relevant line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 phpinfo.local
```

How can I set up virtualhosts in arbitrary directories, and allow Apache and myself to create and modify files and directories below the vhost web root? I managed to pull this off once in the past on a different machine, after a lot of trial and error, but I just can't repeat it this time around.

**update**

In addition to Shane's solution, make sure to reboot after adding yourself to a group. At this point, this setup works as expected. Me and Apache both have write access in  subdirectories that have `775` permissions and are owned by `www-data:www-data` **(not `dan:www-data`)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `www-data` user will also need the ability to traverse the parent directories (the `+x` bit) - I'm betting that `/home/dan/` doesn't have the world allowed to traverse into it?

Comment: `chmod g+x /home/dan` fixes the 403 problem, I can now load the page at `http://phpinfo.local`. However, a nearly identical project in a different location just times out when I try to load it's page. I am now trying to find the relevant difference between the two projects. There shouldn't be any...

Comment: Well, I can't find find a difference between the two sites desides their locations. Permissions are identical, vhost configs are identical except for ServerName and directories. Since the site I used in the example is working now and the problem is different (timeout instead of 403 Forbidden), I think I should mark this answer as correct and start a new question for the other site, if necessary. If I figure it out myself, I'll update the question. Thank you!